# What is the best way to learn security in java A-Z

Tags: security, spring-security, ws-security

I am j2se/jee developer and  new to java security side, and planning to learn more on this subject. Can you help me guiding with proper way/recources to learn security from beginner to intermediate level. I have done google for few days and got few words ( SAML,SACML,Oatuh,OpenID, HTTPS/SSL  etc..).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing would be for you to learn by real problem you got while programming, however  better to have go through below links to get some idea on security side. 
Security:

General/Web Application Security:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-J7OpNFOU4&list=PLSM8fkP9ppPq4sCyQPfKXxKAo4R1ejPDN

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorials/java/security/1

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/java-security-tutorial-step-by-step-guide-to-create-ssl-connection-and-certificates.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/overview/jsoverview.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-sec1/

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Java-Web-services-Axis2-WS-Security-encryption/50709

http://java-security-training-guide.com/

Network security:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0SB6eAnx4Q

Java Script level security:

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Answer (score 0):

None of the concepts you mentioned (SAML,SACML,Oatuh,OpenID, HTTPS/SSL etc..) are Java EE concepts.

First you should start your research by studying generic security. Perhaps the book Network Security Essentials Applications and Standards  would be good for you.

Then, you can see how all of these things are implemented in Java.

Also, follow at least the important journals where these things are discussed on daily bases. For instance, check this site [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/)